# Configure Angular to re-evaluate on blur instead of keypress

Tags: angularjs

By default, it seems that Angular reevaluates its binding from a particular DOM element (e.g Text Input) to the underlying scope property on keypress or paste - i.e, whenever the value in the text input changes.

Is it possible to make it only refresh the binding on blur? I.e. do something like:

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="ctrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="base" ng-update-type="blur"/>
        <input type="text" />
        <span ng-bind="doubled()" />                
    </div>
</div>
```

Take the following JS fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/f76dW/

I would like the doubled span to only update when I move the focus out of the first input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ng-blur`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur) and a dummy variable (`base_` in this case) to achieve that effect: http://jsfiddle.net/f76dW/1/

#### Template

```html
    <input type="text" ng-model="base_" ng-blur="updateBase()" />
```

#### Controller

```js
function ctrl($scope) {

    $scope.base = $scope.base_ = 1000;

    $scope.updateBase = function () {
        $scope.base = $scope.base_;
    };

    $scope.doubled = function() {
        return $scope.base * 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, does this confirm that Angular ALWAYS performs an update to the bound scope property on any type of change to the value of the DOM?

Comment: It makes a change as soon as the `.value` attribute of the underlying DOM element changes. I _think_ that happens on `keypress` event, but this may differ from browser to browser.

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-model options. Using a blur hack is tricky, because a blur may not be a change.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="a.b" ng-change="callScriptThenServer()" ng-model-options={updateOn: 'blur'}"/>
```

Comment: Note: [ngModelOptions](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.16/docs/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions) wasn't added until 1.3.x